# Error in Chrome extension - chrome.windows.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following eventPage.js code:

```
var menuItem = {
    "id": "Wikit",
    "title": "Wikit",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(menuItem);

function fixedEncodeURI (str) {
    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){   
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "Wikit" && clickData.selectionText){    
        var wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + fixedEncodeURI(clickData.selectionText);
        var createData = {
            "url": wikiUrl,
            "type": "popup",
            "top": 5,
            "left": 5,
            "width": screen.availWidth/2,
            "height": screen.availHeight/2
        };              
        chrome.windows.create(createData, function(){});        
    }
});
```

But get two errors:

[Error messages from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weCJx.png)

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you likely already created an item with the ID `Wikit`.

Your second issue is that your `width` and `height` values are not integers. Pass this though `parseInt` first.

e.g.

`"width": parseInt(screen.availWidth/2),`